# Sending compressed file (gzip) though HTTP messes with the encoding

Tags: http, asp.net-core

I have a compressed file.
How do I send it to the browser and make it decode it?

ASP.NET Core suports compression like this:

```
services.AddResponseCompression();
...
app.UseResponseCompresssion
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(file);
});
```

But my file is already compressed. I tried just setting the headers, reading the file and sending the content, but it messes with the encoding.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("compressed.gz");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(file);
});
```

If I just send the file, firefox and chrome try to download it, but do not decompress it.

Proof of that:

```
$ cat compressed.gz | hexdump | head -1
0000000 8b1f 0808 3768 5bc6 0302 6966 656c 742e
# that's the magic number: 8b 1f 08

$ curl -X GET   http://localhost:5000/  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'  --output - | hexdump | head -1
0000000 ef1f bdbf 0808 3768 bfef 5bbd 0302 6966
```

How do I prevent encoding problems?

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you have tried and what is going wrong? Try to provide a [mcve] to get the most help :-)

Comment: I was in a hurry yesterday, sorry!

Comment: I don’t know asp.net but `ReadAllText` looks suspicious in combination with reading a binary file.

Comment: @t.niese OMG, such a silly mistake! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you think that might help others in future, then create an answer out of it showing what that correct function call is, and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @t.niese pointed out, the problem is reading the text by lines.
The proper way to do this task is to return a `FileStreamResult`

Example:

```
Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";
return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open), "text/plain");
```